# Tor and cookies

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I have heard that it is possible to browse with the Tor browser without getting cookies. When I take a closer look it seems like it is excepting cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You're messing two *different* things up:

- **Tor** - an anonymous network of darknet type to keep it's users private. It does not gives a thing about anything protocol-related, including HTTP and including Cookies
- **Tor Browser** - a fork of Firefox focused on privacy. It is designed to work with Tor network, but *actually* it works with *any* TCP/IP connection based network, including clearnet

To avoid cookie-tracks use Firefox addons, the *Tor network itself* has nothing to do with them